# multiple apps in one extension

Tags: magento-1.7, extensions

is it feasible to install simply one extension, that will have multiple context-mixed apps (payment, content, order, etc.) in it, and each app has its own configuration panel?
Does this make sense from an architectural point of view of an extension?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you do it for one customer, I think it makes sense, because it reduces the load of XML files and in the end it doesn't matter were the code lies.

It is important, that the code is there, where your team expects it. So this question should by answered by you in this case.

If you will open source or sell it, I wouldn't do this. Because you are adding complexity where one maybe doesn't need it. We only want to use the payment, not the rest of the module. In this case I would go with "single responsibility" for a module.

Comment: did you ever built something like this and are you able to share it? Would just be interesting, how this was realized.Thanks

Comment: No I split it up. No matter for whom I write it, because I'm alone and if someone else get my project, it is easier for him to go on.